# Removing texture wrapping artifacts in OpenGLES

Tags: textures, opengl-es2, texture-atlas

I'm drawing an 2D array of cubes in 3D space using OpenGLES.  The texture that I have bound is spritesheet-style; that is, it's multiple textures packed into one.  If you look closely at the front of the image below, you can see 1-pixel thick lines that are lighter than the crates.  And, thicker lines in the back of the image.  They are not supposed to be there, and are what I believe to be pixels from another texture in the spritesheet.

I'm using `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST` and `GL_NEAREST` for the min and mag filters, and I've tried all of the different clamping modes and nothing changes (`GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, `GL_REPEAT`, `GL_MIRROR_REPEAT`).

At  first I thought it was float precision error, but now I think it's something else (since using `precision highp float` in the shader makes no difference).

[image: Screenshot showing texture wrapping artifacts]

Comment: Thaty's how mipmap filtering works - every next level texture is x2(x4) smaller and it get progressively smaller and more of a "all colors blended"

Comment: @Kromster he is talking about the lines between the tiles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611745/opengl-black-lines-in-between-tiles

Comment: @Bálint right, thats what I meant. Since TS is sampling from an atlas, he gets neighbour tiles "bleed in".

Comment: @Kromster ah, okay, sorry

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments, helped me get a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was going on.  The problem was not floating point precision, and not that I needed to make my own mipmaps to blend each level correctly.  There were actually 2 problems:

1. I was using the Max Rects packer algorithm with non-power-of-2 sized images to create the texture atlas.
2. I wasn't setting `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL`

What I was doing:

- Use Max Rects on non-power-of-two packing to create a texture atlas.  Textures are aligned at pixel boundaries.
- `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` making blending the texture atlas textures into each other even on level 1

What I'm doing now:

- All textures are power of 2.  128x128 is the smallest sized texture in a 4096x4096 texture atlas.
- `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 7);` - This is new.  Don't allow anything below mipmap level 7, because 4096 / (2^7=128) = 32.  This makes the code stop generating mipmaps once the smallest texture in the atlas becomes 1 pixel by 1 pixel.
- `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` - Now scales down the atlas correctly because all the textures are aligned to 1/32 of the width or height of the atlas rather than 1/width or 1/height.

And now the min filter can use 2 modes without texture bleeding:

- `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`
- `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`

The following 2 min filter modes still have bleeding issues, but I'm not planning on using them anyway:

- `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST`
- `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`

The reason is because they are interpolating the mipmaps to sizes that are not powers of two, which makes the textures in the texture atlas aligned to points in between pixels, causing the bleeding.  The only way I think this can be solved is by adding a border around each texture in the texture atlas.  The only problem with that is that the border would have to be 128 or 64 pixels, the size of the smallest texture or half the size of the smallest texture (if you use half pixel offset).  And that's a huge waste of video RAM.

So I went with `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`:

[image]

## Code

```
uint8_t* pixels = /* Fixed number of pre-generated mipmaps */;
size_t pixels_len = /* length of pixels */;
size_t width = /* width of first mipmap */;
size_t height = /* height of first mipmap */;

assert(pixels_len >= width * height * 4);
unsigned int new_texture;
glGenTextures(1, &new_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, new_texture);
// Rendered smaller than texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
    GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
// Rendered bigger than texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    width,
    height,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pixels
);

// Generate mipmaps
int mipmap_level = 0;
int offset = width * height * 4;
while(width > 1 && height > 1 && offset != pixels_len) {
    // Divide width & height.
    width >>= 1;
    height >>= 1;
    // Increase mipmap level.
    mipmap_level += 1;

    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        mipmap_level,
        GL_RGBA,
        width,
        height,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        0x1401,
        pixels + offset,
    );

    offset += width * height * 4;
}

glTexParameteri(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL,
    mipmap_level,
);
```

Comment: I am facing with exactly the same problem, but still have no luck in solving it. Could you kindly post here the code for loading the texture atlas?

Comment: Just added the code to the answer.  Hopefully it helps!